# Weird result when taking date from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, date, phpmyadmin, timestamp

I want to substract 2 dates and take the result in minutes like the code bellow gives me the answer i want.

```
$to_time = strtotime("2017-03-27 17:31:40");  
$from_time = strtotime("2017-03-27 18:32:40");  
echo "sunolo1: ".round(abs($to_time - $from_time) / 60,2). " minute";
```

But when i try to retrieve dynamically date from mysql using php it doesnt work it returns 0. (date in my table is in timestamp)

```
 $d = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone("Europe/Athens"));

    $dateM = $d->format("Y-m-j H:i:s");
    $result = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT date FROM mytable WHERE id= ? ");

      mysqli_stmt_bind_param($result, 'i', $ids);

      mysqli_stmt_execute($result);

      mysqli_stmt_bind_result($result, $ddd);

  while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($result)){
    $sunolo_krathshs = round(abs($ddd - $dateM) / 60,2);
    echo "sunoloo: ".$sunolo_krathshs;
  }
```

Comment: Debug by checking the values of $ddd and $dateM. Make sure they are of same format

Comment: yeah i print them both with echo and both is corrent (same format like first example) when i print them in while

Comment: If your 'date' column holds timestamps then I think you are subtracting a string from a timestamp. Your $dateM is a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to parse the value of $ddd to a DateTime object, since the easiest way would be to compare DateTime objects.

```
$date = new DateTime();
$ddd = $date->setTimestamp($ddd);

$sunolo_krathshs = round(abs($ddd - $d) / 60,2);
```

Comment: and then i add intval($sunolo_krathshs); and its all perfect

Answer (score 2):

Please check this.

```html
<?php

$datetime1 = new DateTime("2017-03-27 17:31:40");
$datetime2 = new DateTime("2017-03-27 18:32:40");
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
$hours   = $interval->format('%h'); 
$minutes = $interval->format('%i');
echo 'Diff. in minutes is: '.($hours * 60 + $minutes); 

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function while passing the date values for calculation. Something like this:

```
$sunolo_krathshs = round(abs(strtotime($dateM) - strtotime($ddd)) / 60,2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the DateTime class this can be quite simple

```
$result = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT date FROM mytable WHERE id= ? ");

mysqli_stmt_bind_param($result, 'i', $ids);
mysqli_stmt_execute($result);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($result, $ddd);

$to_time = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone("Europe/Athens"));
while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($result)){
    // probably want UTC as date times are stored on the db in UTC
    // but you may need to experiment with timezones here
    $from_date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $ddd, new DateTimeZone("UTC"));   
    echo round(abs($to_date->getTimestamp() - $from_date->getTimestamp()) / 60,2). " minute";
}
```

Answer (score -3):

There is no assigment value operation for variable $ids...

Comment: Obviously this isn't the problem, and this isn't an answer you could leave a comment to assure that he didn't forget to initialize `$ids`